# Transfer numbers from other columns by position to a new column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I will need these columns:`CAD_ADMIN,rank`

```
CAD_ADMIN rank
0507502   001
0507503   002
0507504   003
0507505   004
```

i made the `rank` column like this:

```
dff['rank']= (dff.groupby('CAD_ADMIN').cumcount()+1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)
```

The thing here is that i need to make 
a new column that will have:

The first 5 numbers from `CAD_ADMIN` then the letters 'qw' and then the rest of the `CAD_ADMIN` (6 and 7 numbers in position and then the `rank` column
for example:

```
new_col
05075qw02001   #first line
etc..
```

i tried some lambda functions but it was far from the wanted result.

Comment: Do you need to create the column `rank` or would a solution that just produces `new_col` directly from `CAD_ADMIN` be better? And I assume, we are talking about a pandas dataframe, so I tagged the question with it.

Comment: I need the rank column to be at the end of each line appended as the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [indexing by `str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) with [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
dff['new'] = dff['CAD_ADMIN'].str[:5].add('qv').add(dff['CAD_ADMIN'].str[5:]).add(dff['rank'])
print (df)
  CAD_ADMIN rank           new
0   0507502  001  05075qv02001
1   0507503  002  05075qv03002
2   0507504  003  05075qv04003
3   0507505  004  05075qv05004
```

If rank column is not necessary in output `df`:

```
rank = (dff.groupby('CAD_ADMIN').cumcount()+1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)
dff['new'] = dff['CAD_ADMIN'].str[:5].add('qv').add(dff['CAD_ADMIN'].str[5:]).add(rank)
print (dff)
  CAD_ADMIN           new
0   0507502  05075qv02001
1   0507503  05075qv03001
2   0507504  05075qv04001
3   0507505  05075qv05001
```

Solution with `format` and list comprehenion:
:

```
rank = (dff.groupby('CAD_ADMIN').cumcount()+1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)
dff['new'] = ['{}qv{}'.format(x[:5], x[5:]) for x in dff['CAD_ADMIN']] + rank
#python 3.6 solution
#dff['new'] = [f'{x[:5]}qv{x[5:]}' for x in dff['CAD_ADMIN']] + rank
print (dff)
  CAD_ADMIN           new
0   0507502  05075qv02001
1   0507503  05075qv03001
2   0507504  05075qv04001
3   0507505  05075qv05001
```

---

Solution if need column `rank` in output `DataFrame`:

```
dff['rank'] = (dff.groupby('CAD_ADMIN').cumcount()+1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)
dff['new'] = ['{}qv{}'.format(x[:5], x[5:]) for x in dff['CAD_ADMIN']] + dff['rank']
print (dff)
  CAD_ADMIN rank           new
0   0507502  001  05075qv02001
1   0507503  001  05075qv03001
2   0507504  001  05075qv04001
3   0507505  001  05075qv05001
```

Comment: What is the difference between those? You delete the rank column from the dataframe eventually?

Comment: @user9988562 - Yes, it depends if need column rank or not. If not, then is not necessary create it.

Comment: @user9988562 - So if need create new column `rank`, add to code and then delete this solumn, better is create `rank` `Series` and add it to joined strings. It is up to you.

Comment: You mean that there is not need to create it in the first place?or to delete it after you combine it with the rest of the columns in the column?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I mean it is not necessary create new column if dont need them in final DataFrame.